# jquery mobile custom css?

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, jquery-mobile

hi I just finished designing a mobile web app and now want to start the development process. I was reading that it is very hard to use custom css with JQuery Mobile and therefore the design I have just completed cannot be used with such a framework.

Is there a solution or maybe another framework which supports the features of JQM but at the same time allows the developer the freedom to use his own design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont know were you were reading that its hard to use custom css with jquery mobile. Its is designed to be easly customised. Check http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/

If you are interested in customised content on your site check this part of documentation: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/content/index.html - for example layout grids can help you with your individual design

Other framework I can suggest is yui http://yuilibrary.com/ (for example css grid part in documentation can also help you with your custom design)

Good luck!

Comment: Omg, really, easily customized? Okay i want my navigation bar to have 20px more padding. good luck 'customizing' that. jQuery mobile is NOT easily customizable by far. yes, it's possible to create 'swatches', but those are not themes. good luck playing around with changing colors in their 'themeroller', you won't get to modify structural CSS at all. you'll have to override their CSS the hard way if you need big changes. again, NOT customizable at all...

Comment: @Michael I agree with you. However, so far, I have not found any good solution to handle tailor-made designs. Would you have any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

There is a huge misconception about using your own styles with JQM that I have found everywhere, including SO. The trick to using your own CSS with JQM is in how you write your own CSS. In general, you must first specify the element you wish to overide the JQM CSS with an id, and then attach the JQM class to that ID. For example, to remove the JQM standard link border CSS from an image link, where #img_button_1 is the ID given to the anchor parent of the image, you would code your CSS like so...

The HTML...

```
<a id="img_button_1" data-role="button" data-theme="none" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-inline="true"
   href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
    <img src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo1w.png" alt="Google" />
</a>
```

Your override CSS...

```
#img_button_1 .ui-btn-inner { border: 0 }
```

I answered this before with some working examples that can be found here

[Jquery Mobile - Using image as link - Blue line below image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593259/jquery-mobile-using-image-as-link-blue-line-below-image/17554034#17554034)

You can use the same technique for resolving all your JQM CSS conflicts. Now you can reconsider using JQM to achieve your desired results knowing how simple it is to resolve these conflicts by using CSS specicivity in your own CSS. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I too had similar problem with JQM but I made decision early and switched to [jQTouch](http://jqtouch.com/)
because of its simplicity. Of course, it does not offer as many widgets as JQM.

Looking at your requirement, I recommend you go for **jQTouch** as it has minimal CSS ( not as bulky as **Sencha Touch** or **JQM**). You should be able to roll your own theme in few hours.

Answer (score 1):

JQM is not easily customizable see here:

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/use-custom-css-with-jquerymobile

The quick and dirty way is to add a "style" tag directly to the div/input/text area, what have you. This easily overrides the default jQuery css.

Or, if you are changing the style of all the inputs for example, then you can copy the jquery style class, and paste that into your css. This will also override JQM styling, but note that doing this changes every instance where that particular class is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I have easily customized jQuery mobile applications in design. The work around is to have your style="" written at after the classes; which adjusts the scripts prior. It may not be traditionally clean, but it is a quick fix until a better solution is found.

For example:

```
<div data-role="header" role="banner" style="background:none; border:none;"> 
    <div class="ui-logo" ></div> 
</div>
```

**A great alternative I have found is to place the custom CSS class after all of the other jQuery ui classes, and specify each of the main relevant class properties as "!important". This is the solution I use now.**