# Jquery Mobile - Using image as link - Blue line below image

Tags: jquery, image, mobile, hyperlink, formatting

I'm attempting to use thumbnail images as buttons in JQM. I'm aware that JQM adds some formatting and styles.

I have the image buttons looking and behaving exactly as I want them except for one thing -- on my phone a blue underline is added to all images that are being used as links.

Some info:
-My phone is a Samsung Galaxy SII Skyrocket - Android version 2.3.5
-The blue line does not appear in the most recent versions of Firefox, Google Chrome, IE, or Safari.
-The functionality appears to work exactly as expected.

Here is the code:

```
<a data-role="button" data-theme="none" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-inline="true" href="/path/to/link"><img src="path_to_img" alt="Picture" /></a>
```

Does anyone know why this blue line is appearing below the thumbnail/buttons?

EDIT:
Here is a screenshot of the blue line that I'm talking about:
http://i41.tinypic.com/2rhtvz8.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. This rule removes the blue line added by JQM:

```
.ui-li:last-child, .ui-li.ui-field-contain:last-child {
border-bottom: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting CSS like

```
border: 0;
```

specifically on the `IMG` tag?

**EDIT**: I just had a similar experience: A single white border added to an image. See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H3aKk/).

My workaround (commented out in the code example on jsFiddle) was to remove the border from the `.ui-btn-inner` class.

Comment: I have tried that, and it did not work. I tried rules to remove the border from the image, and basically every CSS class that gets added by JQM. No luck on any.

Comment: Updated my answer - maybe it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Add this on your `<a>` tag:

`style="text-decoration:none;"`

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a user-agent stylesheet property that is not normalized?

Comment: I really don't think so. The only CSS that has been modified from the JQM CSS is removing the padding for the .ui-btn-inner class. I've tried with and without the CSS change and it didn't fix it -- blue line was still there.

Comment: have you tested eliminating any possible user agent styles? like a.ui-btn-inner img { border: none !important }

Comment: I tried a whole bunch of them (including the one you just posted) and none of them seemed to do the trick. I went through all of the CSS rules through Firebug and none of them seemed to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this question, and had to stop to give the correct answer, and spare the pain I went through over a year ago trying to come up with a standard way to address CSS formatting conflicts with JQM styles. I hope this will save all of you some of the hair I lost back then figuring this out.

The solution lies in CSS specificity. All you need to do with any formatting conflict in JQM is to first apply an id to the element you wish to override JQM formatting with your own CSS.

Next, in your own CSS, specify that the class be applied to the **id** of the container.

```
#img_button_1 .ui-btn-inner {border: none !important;}
```

It's as simple as that.

One more important thing, and that is that load order of the external CSS files is significant, and you will want to load your own CSS **after** JQM CSS.

I have forked a working example of Ryans jsFiddle to show the small difference to his solution, which was at least on the right track here in this post.

[http://jsfiddle.net/Z8Xnx/14/](http://www.wikipicplus.com/JQM_CSS_Overide_Example.html)

Another added benefit with this approach, is you do not have to alter the JQM CSS at all, and can leave it alone. I have successfully used this approach to resolve every JQM CSS conflict I have run across since figuring out this specicivity requirement issue.
Hope this helps everyone with an easy solution to their JQM style conundrums.

** **UPDATE** **

It has been noted to me that this method does not work with the latest version of JQM (1.3.0b1), and that is not correct. I have investigated and found this to be a problem with the imlementation of this version of JQM at jsFiddle. To prove this, I have put up an example page on my own space with the exact same code as that shown in the jsFiddle example. This means as of my writting, you really can't trust anything at jsFiddle using the lastest version of JQM from the options. Just a heads up, and you can find the working implementation at...

[jQuery Mobile CSS Override Example](http://www.wikipicplus.com/JQM_CSS_Overide_Example.html)

Answer (score 0):

First things first with all styling issues on JQM - set the data role to "none".

```
<a data-role="none" href="/path/to/link"><img src="path_to_img" alt="Picture" /></a>
```

That should stop JQM trying to add most preformatted styles to the element, it will either fix your problem or allow you to then style it up from scratch and avoid th